# Using multiple formulae in one table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I've got a table with multiple floating point rows and I'd like to
round each of them.

```
+------------+-------------|
| 445.211219 | 1679.315626 |
| 415.789521 | 1566.561511 |
| 435.918622 | 1689.427872 |
+------------+-------------|
| 424.203660 | 1592.293310 |
| 400.164057 | 1628.415460 |
| 410.473361 | 1507.498568 |
+------------+-------------|
| 463.528003 | 1593.778433 |
| 459.144001 | 1487.695008 |
| 338.498464 | 1459.291475 |
```

So my first approach was

```
#+TBLFM: $3=round($3) $4=round($4)
```

But that produces

```
+----+-------------|
|  0 | 1679.315626 |
|  0 | 1566.561511 |
|  0 | 1689.427872 |
+----+-------------|
|  0 | 1592.293310 |
|  0 | 1628.415460 |
|  0 | 1507.498568 |
+----+-------------|
|  0 | 1593.778433 |
|  0 | 1487.695008 |
|  0 | 1459.291475 |
```

Two lines

```
#+TBLFM: $3=round($3)
#+TBLFM: $4=round($4)
```

doesn't work either - only the first one is applied.

How do I define formulae for more than one column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formulas are `::`-separated. Try :

```
#+TBLFM: $3=round($3)::$4=round($4)
```

You may want to use [these commands from the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html) to edit formulas, rather than editing the TBLFM line by hand, they're very convenient :·)